# Monotone Class closed under complementation.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

Are Monotone classes always closed under complementation? I attempted to construct a counterexample however I was not able to do so.

Recall the definition of a monotone class is:

$C \subset P(X)$ for some set $X$ is called a monotone class if it is closed under countable union of an increasing sequence of sets. And similarly, is closed under countable intersection for a decreasing sequence of sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $C = \{ c \subseteq \mathbb N \mid 0 \in c \}$. $C \subseteq \mathcal P(\mathbb{N})$ is closed under unions and intersections (hence monotone) but not under complements, since $\mathbb N \setminus \{0\} \not \in C$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, this would also show that monotone classes are not closed under set difference in general, correct?

Comment: @oliverjones Correct.